# When I write in the terminal using python in VScode i can never write in the terminal like the tutorials are doing. how do I fix that?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

[this is what i get when I write in the terminal, (Im sorry, im super new)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENCWN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are typing in a [z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell), but you are trying to execute python code. To enter python's interactive mode, you can simply type `/usr/bin/local/python3` (or `python3` directly might work if things are setup correctly on your computer).
Once you do that, you should see something like

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Jul 16 2021, 11:47:35) 
[Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

in which you can type your lines of python code